# apache2 virtual host html page link goes to default page

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

Trying to learn how to setup virtual hosts on Apache2.4.

I have 2 or more virtual hosts, "vhost1", "vhost2", and so on.  These virtual hosts have a "index.html" in their DocumentRoot, and a "step2.cgi" in their {DocumentRoot}/cgi-bin directory.

The goal is that from the index.html in the DocumentRoot, I want to click on the link contained in that index.html to go to the vhost's cgi-bin directory and run a script from there.

The issue I'm seeing is if I click on the link in the index.html, the link tries to open the indicated file in the default server's DocumentRoot.  And, gets an "error 404" in response.

How do I get a link a relative URL to activate the cgi in the cgi-bin directory of the virtual host that I started with?

I note that if I have a link in the index.html that just refers to "step1.html", that page is correctly display.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

I have a virtual host with the configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *>

 DocumentRoot /srv/www/vhosts/vhost1/htdocs
 ServerName vhost1.local
 ServerAlias vhost1
 ServerAdmin root@server1.local

 <Directory /srv/www/vhosts/vhost1/htdocs/>
  DirectoryIndex index.cgi
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  AddHandler cgi-script .pl
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI -Includes
  Require all granted
 </Directory>

 <Directory /srv/www/vhosts/vhost1/cgi-bin/>
  DirectoryIndex index.cgi
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  AddHandler cgi-script .pl
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI -Includes
  Require all granted
 </Directory>

 CustomLog /srv/www/vhosts/vhost1/logs/access_log vhost_common
 ErrorLog /srv/www/vhosts/vhost1/logs/error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

The index.html looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>
        My page title
     </title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <a href="http://vhost1.local/cgi-bin/step2.cgi">
              Click here:
     </a>
     <a href="step1.html">
              or  here:
     </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the error in the error_log file is:

> [Sun Oct 20 00:33:37.611844 2019] [cgi:error] [pid 3770] [client
>   192.168.0.103:63367] AH02811: script not found or unable to stat: /srv/www/cgi-bin/step2.cgi, referer: http://vhost1.local/

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

It appears that one needs a "scriptalias" directive before the "" directive.

Like:

```
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/srv/www/vhosts/vhost1/cgi-bin/"

 <Directory /srv/www/vhosts/vhost1/cgi-bin/>
  DirectoryIndex index.cgi
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  AddHandler cgi-script .pl
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI -Includes
  Require all granted
 </Directory>
```